Linux usb-gadget confifs hardware id mapping
I need to create a linux usb gadget that reports a hardware id with the format "HID\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY&MI_0Z&Col0N". I know how PID, VID, and MI are mapped to configfs, but I can't figure out a way to have collections so I can control N.
Which configFS directories and files are associated/mapped with collections?
Thank you,
